# Makefile won't unload conficting module

Tags: eclipse, makefile, kernel-module

I have a *Makefile* I am running through Eclipse on Linux. It has the following form:

```makefile
SHELL:=/bin/bash
all:
     module unload conflicting/module/1.2.3
     module load correct/module/1.2.3
     ifort myStuff
```

When I tell Eclipse to "Build All", I get the following error:

```
 correct.module.123(23):ERROR:150: Module 'correct/module/1.2.3' conflicts with the currently loaded module(s) 'comflicting/module/1.2.3'
```

I know the modules conflict, that's why I unloaded the first one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each line of your recipe runs in a separate shell.  Thus, having inherited its environment from `make`'s parent shell, your

```
    module unload conflicting/module/1.2.3
```

line correctly unloads the specified module from the shell in which it is running, but that affects only that shell.  The `module load` command also inherits its environment from the parent shell, and since that was not affected by the previous command in the recipe, it still contains the conflicting module.

There are at least two possible solutions:

1. Take environment module manipulation out of the makefile.  It is normally accounted the responsibility of the user to set up `make`'s environment appropriately for the build to be performed.  In particular, environment module manipulation is very system-specific -- some systems don't even have the `module` command, and module names and the list of available modules are not necessarily consistent -- and I don't think that belongs in a makefile.
2. But if you insist on doing module manipulation then convert your multiline recipe into a single(-logical)-line recipe:

   ```
   SHELL:=/bin/bash
   all:
       module unload conflicting/module/1.2.3; \
         module load correct/module/1.2.3; \
         ifort myStuff
   ```

   The end-of-line backslashes cause `make` to join the multiple physical lines into one logical line, which then requires the semicolons to break up that line into multiple separate commands.

Comment: So it seems that the "correct" way to do things, then, would be to load the module in the Eclipse environment, rather than within the Makefile?  You wouldn't happen to know how to do that?  It's difficult to search for because "modules" also describes an unrelated concept within the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Frank, if you are building the project from within Eclipse, then the *easiest* way to do things would probably be to perform the module unloading and loading in the shell from which you start Eclipse, or one of its ancestor shells.  There may be alternatives based on adjusting your project configuration in Eclipse, but my Eclipse-foo is too weak these days to make a specific recommendation in that area.